# change the value from another component but its not reflecting on the DOM

Tags: angular

Initially i am setting the value in home component through a function and I am triggering function in profile component but the value on the DOM is not changing & profile is a child component

Here is the code

Home component:

```
//Value is not getting changed after trigger the function in profile component

@Component({
  template: `
     <span>data Filter: {{dataname}}</span>    
    `,
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
dataname = '';
ngOnInit() {
    this.productlist('abcd');
}

 productlist(any){
     this.dataname = any;
 }
}
```

profile component:

```
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
@Component({
  providers: [HomeComponent],
  template: `
     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="dataname"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveUser()">Save</button>
    `,
  styleUrls: ['./Profile.component.css'],
})
export class ProfileComponent {
  dataname = '';
  constructor(
    private home : HomeComponent, 
  ) {
  }
 ngOnInit() {
 }
saveUser(){
   this.home.productlist(this.dataname);
}
}
```

I am getting the value in the function when i trigger in profile component but its not changing in DOM
Please help me with this issue.

Comment: please read different ways of component interaction : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fta5ji?embed=1&file=src/app/data.service.ts)**

Create a DataChange Service:

```
export class DataChangeService {
  constructor() {}

  public status: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");

  changeData(value: any) {
    this.status.next(value);
  }
}
```

profie.component:

```
  constructor(private changeService:DataChangeService) {}

  saveUser() {
    this.changeService.changeData(this.dataname);
  }
```

home.component

```
  constructor(private changeService: DataChangeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeService.status.subscribe(val => {
      this.dataname = val;
    });
  }
```